# Mobile Website not Responsive despite web and emulator showing it works

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

My website (kitchhomedesign.com) is responsive on desktop web and mobile emulators.  When I use a real iPhone it does not respond correctly.  Thoughts on where to start on debugging?

Mobile Emulator:
http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://kitchhomedesign.com

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Grace Miller">
    <title>Welcome to Kitch Home Design</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--Font Awesome Icons--> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not responding correctly? You can't debug on a phone and it's unlikely anyone is going to recreate your page for you and jump back and forth between devices trying to solve the problem.

Comment: It shows up mobile friendly on emulators but it is not mobile friendly on the device.  Looking for ideas on how to fix.

Comment: I understand the essence of the problem but your question is too abstract to expect an answer from anybody.

Comment: Found this great link on how to fix (below).  GoDaddy uses iFrames when forwarding with Masking.  To fix, you need to setup DNS entries appropriately and Forward without masking inside GoDaddy.  http://www.frontendjunkie.com/2015/04/save-money-by-moving-your-static.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your website is not showing responsive is that you are showing it in an iFrame on kitchhomedesign.com. If you go directly to kitchhomedesign.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com it is working just fine.

Comment: Great feedback.  This gave me exactly what I needed to conduct the right search online and find the answers.  Thank you!!  Check it out now - site looks great!